# The Gallery Access

Tags: android

I'm working on an app that lets you display a photo to the Activity and then share it. I'm trying to get the code to work for it to get a image from the gallery. It works for the Google photos app, but force closes when it comes to other apps. Could I get some help for this?

package app.com.example.android.shoutoutapp;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import    android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends      Activity {

private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;

private String selectedImagePath;
private ImageView img;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.targetimage);

    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.add_photo))
            .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
                }
            });
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
            img.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
        }
    }
}

    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
}
```

Comment: Krishna V. Im not on my computer. On the app. I don't have access to wi-fi. I'm trying though

Answer (score 0):

in manifest,
 to get the Images from other apps we need this permission,

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```